# Can my browser / computer / mobile run Archilogic?

Tags: archilogic

Which browsers are supported?

On which mobile phones can I use the application?

On which devices does it run best or how do I get the best results?

Which VR devices can I use?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Archilogic runs entirely within your Browser. So all you need is a modern Browser that supports webGl.

Here you can test [your browser](http://webglreport.com/):

The following browsers currently support WebGL – the technology the application is based on:
Microsoft Internet Explorer 11+, Microsoft Edge, Google Chrome, Mozilla Firefox, Apple Safari 8+

If you run **Internet Explorer 10** or older, you need to update to version 11 or use a different browser like Chrome or Firefox.
If you run **Safari 7** or older on Mac OSX, you can enable WebGl following these instructions:

> Open the Safari menu and select Preferences Click the Advanced tab in
>   the Preferences window Then, at the bottom of the window, check the
>   Show Develop menu in menu bar checkbox Then, open the Develop menu in
>   the menu bar and select Enable WebGL or use a different browser like
>   Chrome or Firefox.

On mobile devices iOS 8 + and Android 4.4 + are supported.

The best results you get on a device with a strong GPU component (a good graphics card). however the application is designed to be very user and mobile friendly - this means that you get a mobile-friendly version for your model - the files are smaller to download and less heavy on your mobile's graphics card and processor.